# Facebook server side login without user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a program (in Meteor / Node) which will periodically search Facebook for updates as a cron job.

It does not need to do so on behalf of a user, I'd like it to just do it as the app itself. It will never post, only search.

The reason for this is that there won't be a user there - the script is running on the server.

Is it the case it still has to nominally authenticate as Facebook user? If so, will that user's authentication expire after 60 days? And then what - because the user is not there to alert them to re-authenticate.

Finally, I don't understand why Facebook docs cover so many obscure scenarios, but not this seemingly obvious one.

Comment: you can do login without user or username/password behalf of user..

Comment: Can you point me at anything - the docs are so confusing I seem to have looked past this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/ you can use graph api to make search

Comment: "Searches across page and place objects requires an app access token.
All other endpoints require a user access token."

So it looks like the answer to this question is basically no, you must get the user to authenticate.

Comment: You can use the Graph API Explorer to get an Access Token for a User, without having to implement the OAuth flow. Just select your app in the upper right dropdown.

Comment: Presumably it will expire after two hours though?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why I have minus 1 for this, seems like a valid question to me.

The (hack) answer is to go to the graph explorer and get a valid access token, making sure you are using the graph explorer with the app id for the app you want to eventually be using ie. select it from top right drop down. Thanks @tobi.

Now you have a token that will last an hour. You can exchange it for a longer term token by using this url

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&fb_exchange_token={token you just generated}

Don't try and do this last step via the graph explorer - it fails silently.